# how to enforce CSP validation for application running on localhost

Tags: google-chrome, websphere, content-security-policy

When the application developed by me has migarted to upper environment I received CSP https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy error. This is due to inline Javascript that I understand. Now to fix it I want to reproduce the issue in local and text the fix. But when I ran the application in my local I am not able to reproduce the CSP error. 
Is there any way to force the application running in localhost to go through CSP validation ?
Application running on WAS 8.0 with JSF 2.1 and Chrome version 58

Comment: In case you are still looking for an answer, please provide more details on "upper environment": old environment and the updated environment.

Answer (score 0):

With the available information in your question, I can think of 3 possibilities:

1. You might be using an old browser at your local machine to test the issue, which doesn't support CSP and is therefore ignoring the header. (If the browser you are using for testing on your local machine is chrome 58, then this may not be the issue).
2. Instead of specifying the value of the header as 'self', you might have specifically given localhost in the URL and therefore when the URL does not contain localhost, but your domain name, browser gives CSP error.
3. If a library is updated, then may be the new library is violating your CSP header by adding some new inline script or inline CSS to your page.